# Why does my mobile site scroll left to lots of white space

Tags: android, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I am really struggling to understand why the portrait mobile version of my website scrolls way left!

I have removed the header image which is quite large but the width still scrolls of to right of the screen!

I have applied the common viewport code in my head tag and played around with css widths but to no avail.

There should be no scrolling left or right on the mobile version of my site.

Any clue as to what element/@media set-up is causing this width issue with the mobile css?

[danieltuffour.com](http://www.danieltuffour.com)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick glance at the developer panel, you're using `min-width:900px` right now, which always keeps a width of `900px`, regardless of what the `width` tag is set to. The easiest fix is to do the following:

```
#mediacontainer {
  min-width:100%;
  /* other css... */
}
```

This way, the content will always be 100% the width of the viewport. Now, another alternative would be to set a `max-width` on the element which would prevent it from overflowing the screen:

```
#mediacontainer {
  width:900px;
  max-width:100%;
  /* other css... */
}
```

This method allows you to specify 900 pixels, but prevents it from displaying that way if there aren't 900 to use.

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work! '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">'

Comment: Are you testing on a computer, or on a phone? Your query is `@media only screen` right now, which means a computer won't trigger the query. Change it to `@media screen` **and** change your triggers to `min-width` and `max-width`. It'll work.

Comment: Ok, I looked again - the `min-width` is still being applied. Rather than setting an absolute pixel value, you should use a percentage because it will scale appropriately every time. Either that or just use `width` rather than `min-width` so you don't have to reset both every time.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am testing on a smartphone. There is still loads of white space to the right. I changed ' <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">' to initial-scale=0.2 which reduced the overall width. Do you think the browser is processing this line of code twice and "doubling" the viewport somehow?

Comment: Short answer, no. Initial scale has to do with pixel ratio, so lowering that number will shrink your site. I'm updating my answer right now with more complete code and explanations.

Comment: I tried the width: 100% on then changed it back after it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you Brian. It's literally driving me nuts. Bear in my I am developing through cargocollective and there may be mobile css being applied that I cannot access as it is a cargocollective native template.

Comment: Brilliant. Turns out I had to change it in the main css not in the mobile css!